# How do you put custom files into Android/data/com.package.name/files/ folder?

Tags: android

where or maybe 'how' i am supposed to put files that will be available in `/storage/x/Android/Data/my.package.name/files/` folder after installing my application on device?

Basically, i need installer to extract these files to this app so called 'shared storage', i've seen that some applications have, their own files in their /files/ folder but how actually they do that? cant find any info

i have like 2000 files that contain textures and shaders that i need to load when program starts, the best choice is to just use

```
FILE * f = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/my.package.name/files/file.jpg","rb");
```

but first i need somehow to put them there, i cant ask user to kindly copy files from internet to a specific folder x_X

Comment: If you have 2000 files on the internet then your app can download them to indicated folder without user interaction .

Comment: If you want it different then please tell how it should go.

Comment: I thought i can just copy them to one of the folders in a project and android studio will provide an apk with these files so they will be extracted during installation so i can easily access them, by providing the path. I don't want them to be downloaded from the internet. apk will be available in play store if thats relevant, resources are not the solution either cause they need to get extracted each time app runs, i always thought theres a similar installation routine like on windows where you install program by extracting files to a directory....

Comment: Indeed you can place your files in the assets folder of your project. They will be packed with the apk file then. At installation of your app nothing happens automatically. You have to find out if you will use your files directly from assets, wich is a resource, nothing against resources, or that you copy them to some folder on the file system.

Comment: Just logged here, i want to say that i did like you mentioned that means. Placed a zip file to res/raw folder and from there i accessed it like: InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                getResources().getIdentifier("actual_filename",
                        "raw", global_context.getPackageName()));  From there i need to put extracted files into desired location